# Standard Time to Military Time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am somewhat new to SQL and I have seemingly simple query but I can't seem to figure out the correct combination of functions. We receive time data from an external source as a five-character string, for example "0500p". I want to convert this string into military time. The format required for output is a five character string, for example "17:00". 
I have tried

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(5),STD_TM,108)
```

but I think it's not recognizing my "time" as a time since it just outputs the same thing I put in.

Comment: Actually that's "strange time format" to "standard time format" where I come from ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree...but these are the constraints we were given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify a format when converting text to text; you'd need to convert it to a `DATE` value first.  However, in this scenario you don't need to round-trip through `DATE`.  Just:

```
DECLARE @Input CHAR(5) = '0500p'
SELECT
    CAST(CAST(LEFT(@Input, 2) AS TINYINT) + CASE WHEN RIGHT(@Input, 1) = 'p' THEN 12 ELSE 0 END AS VARCHAR(2))
    + ':'
    + SUBSTRING(@Input, 3, 2)
```

This will format "0500a" as "5:00"; if you'd prefer "05:00", that's a simple adjustment.

Comment: Thank you. That was an accurate and fast response. I'm not sure if I will need the leading zero yet but if I do I'll be sure to reply back. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't care about whether it's 17:00 or 5:00 PM. How SQL Server ends up *storing* the time is irrelevant (formatting is for the presentation tier) - you should be focusing on converting the data to the right time value and storing it as the right data type (in this case probably `datetime`, but in modern versions of SQL Server, just `time`).

```
DECLARE @s char(5) = '0500p', @x datetime;

-- first convert it to a datetime-friendly format
SELECT @x = STUFF(@s,3,0,':') + 'm';

-- now some options for output:
SELECT @x, CONVERT(CHAR(5), @x, 108);
```

Results:

```
1900-01-01 17:00:00.000        17:00
```

Be sure that you consider formatting the value as a string ***only in the presentation tier***. It's not really SQL Server's job to handle formatting for display, and your client tools are better suited for that translation anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response. After a little manipulation to align with our table design, I was able to get your answer to work as well. I accepted the first answer a few seconds before your answer came in but many thanks to both of you. I had no idea how this was going to work but come to find out there's not just one but 2 good answers to my problem.

Comment: @Erik Thanks for that info. I feel like it's only fair to the first person that the answer I accepted first, even if by only a few seconds, remain the accepted answer, especially since both answers are equally valid and produce the same desired results.

Comment: @user2917319 That is completely your call. I didn't want to sound like I was pressuring you either way. I just wanted to make sure you knew the possibilities. :)

Comment: Acceptance should be based on the *best* answer, not the "fastest gun in the west".